# heroku free tier add worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using Heroku's [free tier](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) and trying to set up a worker to process delayed_jobs. According to the docs you have access to a worker. I can run a worker process by running `heroku run rake jobs:work`, however that is a one off process. I've looked at heroku's delayed jobs [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) and when trying to run `heroku ps:scale worker=1` I get the following message

```
Scaling dynos... failed
!    Please verify your account in order to change resources (please enter a credit card) For more information, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing Verify now at https://heroku.com/verify
```

How can I scale up a worker dyno with the free plan? Do I really need to enter in a credit card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification)

> Credit card information is not required for free apps without add-ons. It becomes a requirement once you wish to own more than 5 apps at a time, or to use add-ons other than postgresql:dev or pgbackups:plus –– even if the add-ons are free.

It's likely scaling your app to add a worker is considered an add-on, therefore you are required to validate your account.

Comment: do I understand correctly that now the Heroku free tier provides both at the same time one free Web Dyno and one free Worker Dyno?